# Analyze span - two parallel for

Tags: algorithm

If I have an algorithm with two parallel for and I want to analyze the span of the algorithm, what do I have to do?

For example

```
parallel for a=2 to n
    parallel for b=1 to a-1
```

My guess is the span is theta(lg(n)*lg(n)) but I'm not sure. :) Someone who can help or give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of this algorithm. Since time complexity is NOT how much time the algorithm actually takes, but rather how much operations are needed for it [a quote supporting this claim follows], the time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^2)`, as it was if it was not parallel.

from the wiki page: `Time complexity is commonly estimated by counting the number of elementary operations performed by the algorithm, where an elementary operation takes a fixed amount of time to perform`

**Why don't we care for the fact the algorithm is parallel?**

Usually, our cluster size is fixed, and does not depend on the input [n]. let the cluster size be `k` [meaning, we can perform `k` operations simultaneously and the algorithm is `O(n^2)` [for simplicity assume exactly `n^2`]

assume we have an input of size 100, then it will 'take' `(100^2)/k` time. if it was of size 1,000, it would take `(1000^2)/k`, and for n elements: `(n^2)/k`, as you can see, the k is a constant, and the fact that the program is parallel does not change the complexity. Being able to do `k` operations at once, is not better [and even worth, but that's for another thread] then a computer `k` time faster.